What is the value of dual/lagrangian variable of an infeasible problem?
I found some materials saying that: if the primal is unbounded, then the dual is infeasible; If the dual is unbounded, then the primal is infeasible; but it's possible for both the dual and the primal to be infeasible. However, in the book Convex Optimization (Stephen Boyd), it says "if the primal problem unbounded below, the Lagrangian dual problem is infeasible. If the dual problem is unbounded above, the primal problem is infeasible." Which one is correct?
In addition, I am not sure whether we can reverse that. i.e. the dual variable is an infinity if the primal problem is infeasible, is that correct?

Assume primal is minimization while dual is maximization.
If primal is unbounded, $p^* = -\infty$, and if infeasible we set $p^* = +\infty$ (by convention, and easy to understand since if it's feasible, $p^*$ must be a finite value. Similarly, if dual is unbounded, $d^* = +\infty$, and if infeasible we set $d^* = -\infty$.

If primal is unbounded, then dual is infeasible. Hence, $p^* = d^* = -\infty$
If dual is unbounded, then primal is infeasible. Hence, $d^* = p^* = +\infty$

So, strong duality holds. Note that, it can also happen that both primal and dual are infeasible. In such a case,  $p^* = -\infty, d^* = +\infty$. It's like two infinity meet each other (you bend the x-axis to make a circle), and strong duality still holds in that sense.
